# Redirect after delete post in Frontend (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php function delete_post(){
global $post;
$deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true', get_delete_post_link( 
get_the_ID() ) );
if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) {
    echo       '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return 
confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="'.$deletepostlink.'">Delete</a>
</span>';
} }

//Redirect after delete post in frontend
add_action('trashed_post','trash_redirection_frontend');
function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id) {
if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
}
}
?>
<?php delete_post(); ?>
```

Hello, I'm newbie in PHP code and I'm learning code through Wordpress.

I made 'delete' link in the post and it works fine but redirect.

How can I redirect to home after delete post?

The code is not working after delete post.

Thank you.

Comment: not a wordpress user but try placing `wp_redirect(home_url());` under the `echo  '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return 
confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="'.$deletepostlink.'">Delete</a>
</span>';` line?

Comment: @japanGuy that code is not working, thanks :)

Comment: added an asnwer, can you check if it works, if not let me know